# error: use of undeclared identifier 'alertView'?

Tags: objective-c, theos

I'm trying this with Theos & can't figure out whats wrong. When compiling I get this error:
RootViewController.mm:16:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'alertView'

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSI...

Here's my code:

RootViewController.h

```
@interface RootViewController: UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate> {
}
@end
```

RootViewController.mm

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
- (void)loadView {
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Respring Confirmation"
                                                message:@"Are you sure?"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];

[alert show];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        //NO clicked ...do action

    }else{

        //YES clicked ...respring code here

    }
}
}

@end
```

Comment: Missing a } after [alert show];

Comment: Then I get this error: RootViewController.mm:57:1: error: extraneous closing brace ('}')

Comment: Because you have an extra one at the end, before @end

Comment: Yes, I saw that, just too slow, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket after `[alert show];` and have an extra one at the end, just before `@end`. This is what it should look like:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
- (void)loadView {
  self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Respring Confirmation"
                                            message:@"Are you sure?"
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];

  [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex {
  if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
    //NO clicked ...do action
  } else {
    //YES clicked ...respring code here
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me the line of code I put for the "NO" clocked (just to return to the springboard page)?

Comment: `[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES]`? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated: